# Create new array from 2 existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an initial array of dates:

```
Array ( [0] => 2015-11-23 [1] => 2015-11-24 [2] => 2015-11-25 [3] => 2015-11-26 [4] => 2015-11-27 [5] => 2015-11-28 [6] => 2015-11-29 )
```

and an another array of "results":

```
Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( [order_date] => 2015-11-24 [SUM(order_total)] => 1458.5 ) 
   [1] => stdClass Object ( [order_date] => 2015-11-25 [SUM(order_total)] => 1540 ) 
   [2] => stdClass Object ( [order_date] => 2015-11-26 [SUM(order_total)] => 1256 ) 
   [3] => stdClass Object ( [order_date] => 2015-11-27 [SUM(order_total)] => 2516.5 ) 
   [4] => stdClass Object ( [order_date] => 2015-11-28 [SUM(order_total)] => 3436.5 ) )
```

How can I create a new array that returns the dates from the initial array and their corresponding value from the results array, if it exists, but if not return 0?

So far, if $dates is the date array and $day_of_week_array is the results array, I have tried this:

```
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    echo $date."<br>";
        foreach($day_of_week_array as $day_data){
            $day_date = 'order_date';
            $total = 'SUM(order_total)';
            if ($date === $day_of_week_array->$day_date) {
            echo $day_data->$total."<br>";
        }
else { }
}
}
```

However this seems rather convoluted and does not allow me to return 0 if the dates don't match (as the array is nested) , therefore defeating the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I've built a nested foreach loop that, for each date in the initial array, checks to see if this matches the date in the second array and if it does it returns the total value. This however seems very convoluted and leaves me with the problem that I can return a value of 0 if the dates don't match - as the foreach is nested in another one.

Comment: Then show what you have tried (Add you code to the question).

Comment: Done, however I'm sure this has the potential to confuse people further!

Comment: Past here expected output also.

Comment: I think you have to loop `results` array and set values for corresponding element in `dates` array;

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
$new= array();
foreach($day_of_week_array as $day_data) {
    // Check if the date exists
    if (in_array($day_data->order_date, $dates, true)) {
        $new[$day_data->order_date]= array('Date' => $day_data->order_date, 
                                           'Total' => $day_data->{'SUM(order_total)'});
    }
}
$missed= array_diff($dates, array_keys($new)); // Empty dates
foreach($missed as $d) {
    $new[$d]= array('Date' => $d, 
                    'Total' => 0);
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/536555)

Comment: Solution is good but, will it Give `0` as Sum if date not found?

Comment: No. For that have to add an `else` part. Updated

Comment: Still i think it won't work and for date `2015-11-29` it won't give anything. Have you though like this? Because you are iterating  `$day_of_week_array` over `$dates` so it will miss records of `$dates` array.

Comment: Afraid this crashes my page

Answer (score 1):

Consider following code:

```
$result_array = array();
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $found_flag = 0;
    echo $date."<br>";
    foreach($day_of_week_array as $day_data){
        $day_date = 'order_date';
        $total = 'SUM(order_total)';
        if ($date === $day_of_week_array->$day_date) {
            // echo $day_data->$total."<br>";
            $temp_array = array(
                    'date' => $date,
                    'sum' => $day_data->$total
                );
            array_push($result_array, $temp_array);
            $found_flag = 1;
        }
    }
    if(!$found_flag){
        $temp_array = array(
                'date' => $date,
                'sum' => 0
            );
        array_push($result_array, $temp_array);
    }
}

print_r($result_array); //Your ouptut
```

Comment: Afraid this doesn't do the trick, the output I get is as follows - Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 2015-11-23 [sum] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [date] => 2015-11-24 [sum] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [date] => 2015-11-25 [sum] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [date] => 2015-11-26 [sum] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [date] => 2015-11-27 [sum] => 0 ) [5] => Array ( [date] => 2015-11-28 [sum] => 0 ) [6] => Array ( [date] => 2015-11-29 [sum] => 0 ) ) i.e. this doesn't match any of the dates that do exist

Comment: Check what value you are getting here `$date === $day_of_week_array->$day_date`, echo it and try `==` also once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :)

```
foreach($results as $result){
  if(key_exists($result->order_date, $dates)){
    $dates[$result->order_date] = $result->{'SUM(order_total)'};
  }
}
```

Here you have `$dates` array with values from results array for corresponding order_date.